# net6 minimal web API override settings for test

Tags: xunit

**Program.cs**

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string foo = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("foo"); // Is null. Shoudn't be.

public partial class Program{}
```

**Test project**

```
    public class MyWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
            {
                configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(
                    (new Dictionary<string, string?>
                    {
                        ["foo"] = "bar"
                    }).AsEnumerable());
            });
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public Test(MyWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
        {
            _client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder().CreateClient();
```

But the new settings are never added -- when I debug the test `foo` is always `null`.
I don't see how the settings can added, either, because `Program` creates a new builder that never goes anywhere near the `WebApplicationFactory`.

I think this might be something to do with my `Program` needing to read settings in order to configure services, but the settings not being updated by the test system until after the services have been configured?

Can it be made to work?

Comment: Your code for Program.cs looks somewhat strange. You have an empty declaration of the class ``Program`` and a code fragment out of context that creates ``builder`` . What does your ``Program`` really look like?

Comment: The code is just written straight into the `Program.cs` file without a namespace or a class -- the new net6 syntactic sugar nonsense. The `public partial class Program{}` makes it available to the test project.